# CSS / SCSS won't update in ruby on rails running in Docker

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, sass

Hello I'm having an issue in ruby on rails application running in docker environment. When I updated my scss files in my application and run it using `docker-compose build`, `docker-compose up` the scss that I've updated won't update based on what changes I have applied.

There are things that I've configured in my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` directory:

**application.css.scss**

```
@import "front/style";
```

I've added a folder called `front` and inside the `stylesheets/front` directory called `style.scss`

**style.scss**

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset/";
@import "sampscss";
```

I also created `_sampscss.scss` in the `stylesheets/front` directory and imported the `_sampscss.scss` into the `style.scss`

**_sampscss.scss**

```
.regist-block {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto 70px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;

    .inner {
        padding:30px;
    }
    
    #btn-login,
    .btn-login,
    .btn-signup {
        width: 200px;
        line-height: 36px;
        height: 40px;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        background: $color-green;
        text-decoration: none;
        &.btn_confirm_email {
            width:250px;
            border-radius:30px;
            box-shadow:2px 2px 4px -2px #999;
        }
    }
}
```

And then call that class `btn_confirm_email`  into my `index.html.erb` in the `input type submit tag`

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="regist-block">
    <div class="inner">
        <%= f.submit "Send", class: 'btn-login btn_confirm_email' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

But for some reason `scss` files won't update in my end. I did found some similar issues and I tried to run these commands on docker:

```
docker-compose exec web bundle exec rake assets:clean
docker-compose exec web bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

It says that `rake assets:clean # Remove old compiled assets` and
`rake assets:precompile  # Compile all the assets`

But nothing seems to be working and scss files won't update. Also I tried to change some existing styles into my `public/assets` and run `docker-compose up` again but it seems it won't work all the older assets precompiled is still cache into the `public/assets` directory.

Also in my `assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

This one is existing. Any idea how to resolve this issue why scss files won't update and instead the precompiled css files inside `public/assets` directory won't change even though I run `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: can you show docker-compose file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi it seems that deleting the `assets` folder in the `public/assets` directory solved this issue. And also in my `Application.js` I've changed the turbolinks from `//= require jquery.turbolinks` to `//= require turbolinks`. Don't know how it explains this but this solved the issue I did added the gem into my Gemfile `gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.2.0'` may because of some deprecated gems that I've used.